# Slide Toggle using "this"?

Tags: jquery

I'm using several articles with text in one webpage. I just have a short text intro and then a "read more" link to slide toggle the rest of the article.

I'm trying to simplify my code and are looking for a solution to use `this` in some way instead of the need to use a unique class or id for for each block of text and just use one function to handle slide toggle for all hidden text block. I would like some hints how to develop my code, if it's possible to do it that way? I'm not sure.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(".more").click(function(){
$(this).next(".extra").slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="articleContent">
    <h1>Headline 1</h1>
    <p>Text 1 <a href="#" class="more">read more....</a>
    </p>
    <p class="extra">
    Some more text to read 1
    </p>
</div>

<div class="articleContent">
    <h1>Headline 2</h1>
    <p>Text 2 <a href="#" class="more">read more....</a>
    </p>
    <p class="extra">
    Some more text to read 2
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().next()`. See http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...don't use next on this

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s8akQ/3/)

```
 $('document').ready(function() { 
    $(".more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('p').siblings(".extra").slideToggle("fast");
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing happens when I click on the link!?

Comment: Great, now it's working. But I discovered something less good. If I scroll down a bit and click on "read more", the page jumps up to the top of the page! Do you understand how I mean? I want the text to slide toggle for each article, despite that I have scrolled down a bit. Is there a way to limit this? Otherwise the user has to scroll down again and thats not good. Or is this just how the browsers are working?

Comment: I know what your saying...it's because your using a hash `#` as the href.  I have updated my answer to remedy this issue

Comment: Now it's much better! But would you recomend me not using hash tag and instead use some other simple solution? Just click on some other element and not a link? Ideas are welcome. What does .preventDefault(); really do?

Comment: It's up to you, keep the hash or use a div or a span... the `.preventDefault();` prevents the standard action of an element from being triggered. You could use it on forms to prevent submission and such.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jsfiddle with working code: http://jsfiddle.net/6wqsf/

JavaScript:

```
$(".more").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next(".extra").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.articleContent').on('click', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is('.more')) {
        $(this).find('.extra').toggle();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s8akQ/2/).

References:

- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).